# dynamically add hyperlinks to a flex list component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

How can I dynamically add hyperlinks to a list component?

Currently I'm using `list.dataprovider.addItem()` to add items to my list but I can't seem to figure out how I could convert these items into hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `itemRenderer` for the `List` component, which has proper mouse click callbacks for navigating the user to the appropriate location. Something like [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html). [Here](https://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/05/adding-links-to-mx-and-spark-datagrids-using-inline-item-renderers.html) is a second example, with a similar linking functionality.